# CSS flexbox and rotated input range with flex 1

Tags: css, flexbox, transform

I need vertical zoom range input on the left side of page, with 2 buttons and label. It has to be vertically centered on page. I have everything except rotated input. Once I rotate it flex doesn't work and nothing makes sense (e.g. when I change left offset it moves diagonally). I can try random offsets to move the slider back but it will not work same in all browsers. I need to get input into green box.

All I need is input to be rotated (min value should be at bottom) and input should fit green box maximally (like flex=1). I don't want random magic widths/heights/left/top/bottom/right values because those will never work. I want it to actually fit the green box. Is it even possible?

```css
#zoom_controls {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 0.7cm;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 8em;
  top: calc(50% - 4em);
}

#zoom_controls button {
  width: 0.7cm;
  height: 0.7cm
}

#zoom_div {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}

#zoom {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoom_controls">
  <div id="zoom_label">Zoom</div>
  <button>+</button>
  <div id="zoom_div">
    <input id="zoom" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=20>
  </div>
  <button>-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2f6a9q13/1/)?

```css
#zoom_controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}

#zoom {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin: 70px 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="zoom_label">Zoom</p>
<div id="zoom_controls">
  <button>+</button>
  <input id="zoom" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=20>
  <button>-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It uses magic values and is no longer vertically centered on page because main container is now taller than it's content.

Comment: Here's why it is not good solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1e035ry9/1/

Comment: Add `height: auto` to `#zoom_controls`. Now the main container is not taller than its content.

Comment: That still doesn't help. I need to specify input margin width, if I choose 70px it looks ok in chrome but overflows in firefox (https://jsfiddle.net/1s409mzr/). There is no way to tell input to "fill parent"